# How can be exploited Parquet partitions loading RDD in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, partitioning, parquet, shuffle

I have the following dataset in Parquet

```
+----------+----+
|        id|type|
+----------+----+
|7116663998|   B|
|2099372681|   A|
|2029172681|   B|
|2096031909|   B|
|5096031909|   A|
|5096031909|   A|
+----------+----+
```

The dataset is partitioned by type

```
/.../table
  |- type=A
  |- type=B
```

I need to load the dataset as keyed RDD using type as key in order to process it: for example counting by key (actually I need to cogroup it with another smaller dataset).

Running the following code (I already tried without the partitionBy step, too)

```
spark.read
  .parquet(".../table")
  .rdd
  .map(row => (row.getAs[String]("type"), row.getAs[Int]("id")))
  .partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(2))
  .countByKey()
```

I obtain the following DAG

[image]

Considering the fact that I want to use the partitioning strategy already used by Parquet, there is any way in order to avoid shuffling?

Comment: why not read in `".../table/type"`? You will have a list of rdds, no shuffling needed

Comment: @LuckyGuess: what do you mean? to iterate over subdirectories?